# Show only parent folder names?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I show only parent folder names in my editor tabs? Not file and parent folder like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your `settings.json`

```js
"workbench.editor.labelFormat": "short",
```

[image: tabs]

From VSCode docs

```js
// Controls the format of the label for an editor. Changing this setting can for example make it easier to understand the location of a file:
// - short:   'parent'
// - medium:  'workspace/src/parent'
// - long:    '/home/user/workspace/src/parent'
// - default: '.../parent', when another tab shares the same title, or the relative workspace path if tabs are disabled
"workbench.editor.labelFormat": "default",
```

Comment: Thanks, I did that, but I was asking about showing **only** folder names.

Comment: Oh, I looked around and it seems its still not available [Ref: Issue 41909](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/41909). You might want to install the Monkey Patch Extension and Try this extension [nice-index](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stekoshy.nice-index)

Answer (score 0):

From the menus: File > Preferences > Window
You will see a bulleted dictionary of variables under the heading "Title".
Each of these relates to a component of a title string.
Below the dictionary, you will see an editable string of the a forementioned variables.

e.g.
${dirty}${rootName}${separator}${activeEditorShort}${separator}${appName}

Changing the order of these reformats the title string that is used in the tooltips and titles.

Hope this helps.